# UITableViewCells don't take custom value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to make an item feed with a `UITableView` and some JSON objects,
but when I try filling an instance of my custom cell with the JSON data, the `UILabel`s won't change their text.

The JSON has been tested and works. It goes through the loop and creates the right amount of rows. But the text isn't changing to the text from the JSON file.

Here's my code:

**feed.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *FeedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.personeelsapp.jordivanderhek.com/company/bijcasper/nieuws.json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:FeedURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", dataDictionary);

    self.posts = [NSMutableArray array];
    PostsArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"];

    for (NSDictionary *bpdDictionary in PostsArray) {
        // make new post object
        FeedPosts *posts = [FeedPosts InitPost];
        NSLog(@"feed check %@" ,[bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]);
        posts.postTitle = [bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        posts.postProfilepic = [bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
        posts.postDatum = [bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"timeStamp"];
        posts.postMessage = [bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
        posts.postImage = [bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"image"];
        [self.posts addObject:posts];
    }
}

 […]

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section {
    return [self.posts count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *Cellindentifier = @"PostCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellindentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    FeedPosts *posts = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.postTitle.text = @"test title";
   cell.postDatum.text = posts.postDatum.text;
   cell.postMessage.text = posts.postMessage.text;
return cell;
}
}
```

**FeedPosts.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *postTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *postMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *postImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *postProfilepic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *postDatum;

// designated init
+ (id) InitPost;
```

**FeedPosts.m**

```
+ (id) InitPost {
    // init new feed item
    return [[self alloc]init];
}
```

have been getting the following error:

```
-[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your code that shows the setting of the cells `UILabels` with the new text? Please add the missing code to your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: You need to call `reloadData` on your table after loading the data

Comment: there isn't any right now. because im trying to do this in the for loop within the `viewdidload` method @RoboticCat

Comment: @JordivanderHek Huh? You need to create, setup, and return a cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Show that code.

Comment: @rmaddy I am not able to redefine anything within the cellForRowAtIndexPath. 'cell'  doesn't have any property's to work with linked to my labels

Comment: If you don't update any properties of the cell how do you expect to display any data?

Comment: Find a tutorial on how to use a UITableView and study it.  Your problem is that you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @rmaddy code added. question updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared several *UILabel*s in *FeedPosts*.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *postTitle;
```

In the following code, you assign *NSString* (text) to the label object:

```
FeedPosts *posts = [FeedPosts InitPost];
NSLog(@"feed check %@" ,[bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]);
posts.postTitle = [bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Instead, you should set the text for those labels:

```
posts.postTitle.text = [bpdDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Same goes for `postMessage` and `postDatum`.